# Lumia 535 simulates random touches on any screen

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, touch

my Lumia 535 randomly launches apps on home screen, I can't use it normally. Typing is not possible. Any tips on that?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware fault - have you tried taking it to a service centre?

Comment: Yes, but they repaired something else and gave me the phone back. I always can try again.